# UICollectionView randomally not displaying a cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a UICollectionView that that scrolls vertically. It's first cell holds another UICollectionView that scrolls horizontally.

On random occasions, the horizontal UICollectionView loads a cell, and does not displays it.
So, what i can see is a couple of cells, empty space, and some more cells..
I'm having difficulties detecting the cause for this.

The Code looks like this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (collectionView.tag == 1) {

    if (indexPath.section == 1) {

// do some stuff

} else if (collectionView.tag == 999) { // horizontal collection view

    HorizontalCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell999" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self addBorderToCellImageView:cell.imageView];

    [self updateHorizontalCell:cell forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

return [[UICollectionViewCell alloc] init]; // in any case, return a cell.
}
```

second part is this:

```
 // updating cells for collectionView.tag = 999;
- (void)updateHorizontalCell:(HorizontalCell *)cell forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

id obj = self.horizontalProductDataSource[indexPath.row]; // use introspection, and act accordingly.
NSLog(@"section %ld, row %ld", (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row);

if ([obj isKindOfClass:[Product class]]) {

    Product *wishListProduct = (Product *)obj;

    cell.subtitle.hidden = YES;
    cell.title.text = wishListProduct.name;
    NSLog(@"from product: %@", wishListProduct.name);
    NSLog(@"from cell: %@", cell.title.text);
    cell.price.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f %@", wishListProduct.totalPrice, NSLocalizedString(@"Shekel", nil)];

    __weak HorizontalCell *weakCell = cell;

    NSString *imageURL;

    Image *image = [wishListProduct.pictuers lastObject];
    imageURL = image.url;

    [cell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]]
                          placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"] 
                                   success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image){
                                       weakCell.imageView.image = image;
                                   }
                                   failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
                                       logIt(@"error while bringing photos into cells: %@", error);
                                   }];
}
```

any help would be awesome!

Comment: Will you try tableview and collectionview mixup for horizontal and vertical scrolling?

Comment: what do you mean? @DevangiDesai ?

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1 - you can try this example

Comment: I already worked on this. And in my application it is working perfectly fine. I have one tableview + collectionview. It scrolls vertically and each cell scrolls horizontally as well

Comment: thanks @DevangiDesai, but this is not my problem / question. 
it's not that i can't display anything, or having problems with the layout. everything works good. 
the problem is that sometimes i am "missing" a cell...
and it's an existing project, so these changes can't really take place

Comment: Ohh ok. Let me see if i can help

Comment: When that happens, do you have a pointer to the cell? Can you break in the code and see the actual frame of the cell?

Comment: yes i can see the frame, the only thing is that the UI does not display it.
when i scroll over the missing area and the area is hidden, another scroll will display it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a race condition where the UICollectionView is trying to populate the cell when the data source still doesn't have the data available. Later on when you scroll away and back, the cell is then populated with the data that now exists.